# Is there a way to change DocX multitype list style in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-word, docx

I'm using DocX (https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX)  to generate a word document for my project and I couldn't find a way to change the list style from "1 -> a -> i" to "1 -> 1.1 -> 1.1.1", is there anyway to change this?

I've tried googling for a few hours and apparently, DocX or Xceed documentation is really limited

here's my code

```c
document.InsertParagraph( "Adding lists into a document" ).FontSize( 15d ).SpacingAfter( 50d ).Alignment = Alignment.center;
// Add a numbered list where the first ListItem is starting with number 1.
var numberedList = document.AddList( "Berries", 0, ListItemType.Numbered, 1);
// Add Sub-items(level 1) to the preceding ListItem.
document.AddListItem( numberedList, "Strawberries", 1);
document.AddListItem( numberedList, "Blueberries", 2);
document.AddListItem( numberedList, "Raspberries", 1);
// Add an item (level 0)
document.AddListItem( numberedList, "Banana" );
// Add an item (level 0)
document.AddListItem( numberedList, "Apple" );
// Add Sub-items(level 1) to the preceding ListItem.
document.AddListItem( numberedList, "Red", 1 );
document.AddListItem( numberedList, "Green", 1 );
document.AddListItem( numberedList, "Yellow", 1 );

// Add a bulleted list with its first item.
var bulletedList = document.AddList( "Canada", 0, ListItemType.Bulleted);
// Add Sub-items(level 1) to the preceding ListItem.
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "Toronto", 1 );
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "Montreal", 1 );
// Add an item (level 0)
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "Brazil" );
// Add an item (level 0)
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "USA" );
// Add Sub-items(level 1) to the preceding ListItem.
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "New York", 1 );
// Add Sub-items(level 2) to the preceding ListItem.
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "Brooklyn", 2 );
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "Manhattan", 2 );
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "Los Angeles", 1 );
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "Miami", 1 );
// Add an item (level 0)
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "France" );
// Add Sub-items(level 1) to the preceding ListItem.
document.AddListItem( bulletedList, "Paris", 1 );

// Insert the lists into the document.
document.InsertParagraph( "This is a Numbered List:\n" );
document.InsertList( numberedList );
document.InsertParagraph().SpacingAfter( 40d );
document.InsertParagraph( "This is a Bulleted List:\n" );
document.InsertList( bulletedList, new Font("Cooper Black"), 15 );

document.Save();
```

and here's the result

[image: result]

The expected result

[image: result]

Comment: The question is whether this tool provides access to the supporting XML files that link into the document's main xml content. *Styles* control formatting, also number formatting. The correct style would need to be linked to the paragraphs, in place of the one getting assigned with the code you show. If the tool doesn't provide this, you might consider using the Open XML SDK which does provide full access to Office Open XML content.

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks for your advice Cindy, I'll check that out